# Finding true duplicate files in Windows

Tags: windows, optimization

Currently doing a cleanup on an enterprise drive using Windows 7 and have identified a number of duplicate filenames/files. Rather than open each pair of files to compare, is there anyway to see whether or not a number of files are actual duplicates?

As it stands, I can tell that some are exact duplicates by going in and reviewing each file but I'm worried that some may have different text but remain the same filesize which would eliminate the ability to review solely based on filesize.

Comment: piping `md5sum` through `sort` may be fastest. At least you're only touching every file once that way, that be n instead of n-square.

Comment: Eliminate duplicates based on file size mismatch may still be a very good first step as this is a very low-cost comparison.

Comment: If you use md5sum or other checksum, it is not 100% certain that the files are the same just because they match on md5 -- however, doing the md5 checks first and and then comparing the whole file is a good strategy if you need to be absolutely sure since the md5 pseudo duplicates are quite rare -- 1 in 2**32

Comment: @GaryWalker: That is only true in theory, not in practice. Given a 128-bit hash (such as md5) and an assumed 10 million distinct file contents on your harddisk, the chance for a random, accidential collision to happen is about 1 in 10^24. That's about a quadrillion times less likely than winning the lottery -- which means in practice, if the md5 is the same for two files, the files are identical. It is perfectly safe to bet your life on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FC` command as you would use `diff` in linux.

For example `FC file1 file2` or `FC /B File1 File2` for binary files.